# C# static winform controls not appearing

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, controls

Initially I was rather confused. I am starting to understand my code is skipping the second for because my NUD array is static. My setup is this.

Controls.cs is a partial class for AranockCompanion.cs my main winform. I have all of my controls (labels, numiercUpDownS, buttons, textBoxs) which are not created in the designer (programmatically rather) in this file. Then I have 1 file for Enums.cs and one for GameData.cs (basically initializing arrays with information) and one for basic FileIO.cs.

Because of my fileWriting method to dump information about items into a file, I had to make it static. I think it had something to do with the StreamWriter IIRC. So then I had to make my array static/public in the Controls class to access it. Now because it is static.. this happens.

I feel like there is some rather basic underlying issue with static / new / objects and the fundamentals of OOP and the general design of how I have my project setup, but I cannot put my finger on it for the life of me.

Why would the code skip executing a loop prematurely without any type of error and successfully launch the program???

```
    //Equipment Tab Page
    Label[] equipLabels = new Label[skillTotal];
    public static NumericUpDown[] equipCore = new NumericUpDown[skillTotal];
    NumericUpDown[] equipReq = new NumericUpDown[skillTotal];


                #region Equipment
        MessageBox.Show("0_" + skillTotal);
        x = labelEquipSkill.Location.X - panelEquip.Location.X;
        for (int skillCount = 0; skillCount < skillTotal; skillCount++)
        {
            equipLabels[skillCount] = new Label();
            panelEquip.Controls.Add(equipLabels[skillCount]);
            equipLabels[skillCount].Text = GameData.skillsAll[skillCount];
            equipLabels[skillCount].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, skillCount * spacer);
            equipLabels[skillCount].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 15);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("1_" + skillTotal);
        x = labelEquipBase.Location.X - panelEquip.Location.X ;
        for (int skillCount = 0; skillCount < skillTotal; skillCount++)
        {
            equipCore[skillCount] = new NumericUpDown();
            panelEquip.Controls.Add(equipCore[skillCount]);
            equipCore[skillCount].Minimum = 0;
            equipCore[skillCount].Maximum = 255;
            equipCore[skillCount].Value = 0;
            //equipCore[skillCount].Text = GameData.skillsAll[skillCount]; 
            equipCore[skillCount].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, skillCount * spacer);
            equipCore[skillCount].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 15);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("2_" + skillTotal);
        x = labelEquipReq.Location.X - panelEquip.Location.X;
        for (int skillCount = 0; skillCount < skillTotal; skillCount++)
        {
            equipReq[skillCount] = new NumericUpDown();
            panelEquip.Controls.Add(equipReq[skillCount]);
            equipReq[skillCount].Minimum = 0;
            equipReq[skillCount].Maximum = 255;
            equipReq[skillCount].Value = 0;
            //equipReq[skillCount].Text = GameData.skillsAll[skillCount];
            equipReq[skillCount].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, skillCount * spacer);
            equipReq[skillCount].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 15);
        }
        #endregion


    private void buttonVisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int rc = 0; 0 < skillTotal; rc++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + rc);
            //equipCore[rc].Visible = true;
            equipReq[rc].Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

equipCore[rc].Visible results in IndexOutOfRangeException.
equipReq[rc].Visible results in Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Both at index 0.

Which would logically follow that the 3rd for statement is never executed because of an error during the 2nd for. I confirmed the 3rd is fine by commenting out the 2nd.

Any explanation or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a vague, not-very-useful code example, it's impossible to say for sure what is wrong.

That said, `IndexOutOfRangeException`, along with that apparently you are initializing the `equipCore` array once, using a field initializer, suggests that at the time it's initialized, the `skillTotal` variable is still set to its default value of `0`, instead of the `59` you expected to be.

As far as the `NullReferenceException`, that's to be expected if your code throws an exception before populating any of the members of `equipReq`. I presume that if you fix the initialization of `equipCore`, both exceptions will go away.

I hesitate to even post the above as an answer, except that it seems to be about as specific an answer as could be provided given the code example. If this is not enough information to help you find the error in your code, please post a (much) better code example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for good advice on how to post a good, useful question.

Comment: I did verify at several points that the value was 59 using MessageBox.Show(). I'll read up on those two links you've provided. In the mean time I've gone back and updated the original post. It seems the problem stems from the fact that the equipCore was static because I had been trying to write it to file in a separate file within the project.

Comment: I ended up writing a static streamWriter method which accepted a NUD[]. I removed static from everything else. This seems to work and be effective enough while allowing proper display of the controls.

Comment: @Branden: As I wrote, most likely the problem is because the static field `equipCore` is initialized before the `skillTotal` variable is. So you allocated a zero-length array (the default value for `skillTotal`, before you initialize it, is `0`). It sounds like in the process of making everything non-static, you delayed initialization of the array long enough to ensure `skillTotal` has the right value by the time the array is allocated. In other words, the issue is just as I guessed above.

Comment: Actually, you are incorrect. The problem was in the declaration, but it was not in the initialization. I initialized the variable based on an enum. The enum was part of the project and did not change post-compile at any time. The variable array initialized with a proper length (59), not a 0 length. The problem was that a static control (for whatever reason) cannot be added to a control properly and will not throw an exception or error. My problem was that I made the (array containing the) control static when I should have used a method to pass a non-static value into a static method.

Comment: @Branden: if the array was the proper length, you would not have gotten an `IndexOutOfRangeException` trying to index the array with an otherwise valid index value. That's simply a fact. I understand you may yourself be confused about exactly what was wrong and accidentally fixed the problem by rearranging the code. But .NET doesn't throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` on array access just on a whim; it's _always_ because the index is out of range.

Comment: Ok. It took me rereading/rethinking this about 47x, Literally. I am starting to understand though. Using the theory that making it static caused it to default to 0. Being static jumps to the top of the list in initializations, but not declarations?

It was my understanding that an enum was the equivalent of hardcoding the respective number into the code.

This would mean effectively that a static variable, in theory, should have to have a static initialization variable. The IDE/compiler (visual studio 2012 Ultimate in this case) doesn't have an error/warning for that??

Comment: @Branden: your understanding of enums is correct. But I don't see what that has to do with the initialization of the array. You're not saying that the `skillTotal` variable is actually the name of an enum value, are you? As I said, it's impossible to provide _specific_ commentary given the lack of a clear, complete code example. All I can tell you is that you don't get `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you are using an index that is within the valid range of values for the array.

Comment: The reference to the enum just now was to figure out if the problem was that I used an enum reference during the initialization. I was trying to narrow it down between hardcode, enum, variable and static variable and how each would affect that outcome. I was also trying to understand the how static affected the order of operations on declaration and initialization of fields and members. My googling ended up being a bit lacking in those answers.

Comment: @Branden: with [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be possible for your questions to be answered here. Without such, yes...unfortunately, you are pretty much on your own in figuring the questions out. :(